# Save image to Derby Database with Java

Tags: java, image, javafx, derby, filechooser

I have Problem to Save My Image Using File Chooser in derby Database. I want to build a File Chooser Method to get image from User and save the image into database . but now the image Would not be save in my database.
Please Help me.
Thank You

My Tables are as follow:

```
-- create table LABORATORY(
-- ID INT NOT NULL,
-- TESTERS_ID INT NOT NULL,
-- PATIENTS_ID INT,
-- AZMAYESH BLOB
-- PRIMARY KEY(ID));
```

And My Class code :

```
public class Database {

//FileInputStream fis = null;
//PreparedStatement ps = null;
private Connection connection;
private ResultSet resultSet;
private Statement statement;

public Database() throws SQLException{/*nabayad public bashe*/
    try{
        String userName="reza";
        String password="reza";
        String hostURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reza";
        connection=DriverManager.getConnection(hostURL,userName,password);
        statement=connection.createStatement(TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    }
    catch(SQLException err){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, err.getMessage());
    }

}
public void azmayesh() throws SQLException, IOException {
    int id=LastIdOf("LABORATORY");
    String INSERT_PICTURE = "insert into LABORATORY(ID,TESTERS_ID,PATIENTS-ID,AZMAYESH) values (?,?,?,?)";
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        fileChooser.setTitle("Open text file");
        fileChooser.setInitialDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        fileChooser.getExtensionFilters().addAll(
                new FileChooser.ExtensionFilter("image Files", "*.jpg")
        );
        File file = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_PICTURE);
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        //ps.setInt(2, id);
        //ps.setInt(3, id);
        ps.setBinaryStream(4, fis, (int) file.length());
        ps.executeUpdate();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Azmayesh Ersal shod.");
        //connection.commit();
        //ps.close();
        //fis.close();
}

}
```

Comment: You have mentioned `mysql`, but you are trying to connect to `derby`.

Comment: Hi, my bad , How to Change the code to connect to mysql?

Comment: Update your hostUrl to match your localhost database. Ex. jdbc:mysql://...

Comment: am Using Java netbeans default Database, Is it derby or mysql?

Comment: with String userName="reza";
    String password="reza";
    String hostURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reza";  I am connect to data base.

Comment: Hey @Reza can you describe " the image Would not be save in my database". Is there any error? if yes, post it.

Comment: Hi Dear Uluk Biy, the project build successful, I am using JavaFX to use that method to save image in my database , after I call the method there is a red lines appear in my netbeans  IDE .

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
    String userName="reza";
    String password="reza";
    String hostURL="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/reza";
```

to this

```
    String userName="mysqlusername";
    String password="mysqlpassword";
    String hostURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysqldatabasename";
```

Change `localhost` to your hostname or IP. `3306` is default port for MySQL.

> **NOTE:** You should have mysql-jdbc-connector in your classpath.

Comment: I am Using Java netbeans default Database, Is it derby or mysql?

Comment: sorry my bad, it is derby database . would you please help me how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if(request.getParameter("PhotoFiled")!= null && request.getParameter("PhotoFiled").length()> 0) 
  {
     FileInputStream Photograph_Stream = new FileInputStream(request.getParameter("PhotoFiled"));
     if(Photograph_Stream.available()>0)
     {
          ImgBn.Photograph = new byte[Photograph_Stream.available()] ;
          Photograph_Stream.read( ImgBn.Photograph, 0, Photograph_Stream.available()); 
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering , would you please send me the final code?